# Firebase on change event. How to know who changed data?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

On child_changed event I receive changed data but don know who changed it, is there any possibility to get this information ?

```
database.ref('projects').on('child_changed', snapshot => {
    // something like
    // if (snapshot.userID === currentUserId)
    // if current user did changes
    //    do nothing    
    // } else {
    //    update UI
    // }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information isn't available.  You would have to require the client to write the UID of user into the location being changed, and make sure that value is correct using security rules to enforce that the write contains only the current user's UID.